# Why is TreatAsContent () used in Exclusion script while referring the Content Block?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, exclusion-script

I have written the logic of my exclusion script in 'code snippet' Content Block. Which returns a true / false value.

Then I am referring this Content Block from Exclusion Script something like this,

```
TreatAsContent(ContentBlockByKey("1234567890")) > 0
```

This works as expected. But my questions is why cant we call the ContentBlockByKey() directly and why should be use TreatAsContent() around it? Cant we skip writing TreatAsContent as ContentBlock is the one returning the value?  What makes the difference in using TreatAsContent() around the ContentBlockByKey ? This is confusing to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TreatAsContent](https://ampscript.guide/treatascontent/) function forces AMPscript and personalization strings to be evaluated in the specified input string, while the [ContentBlockByID](https://ampscript.guide/contentblockbyid/) function returns the content stored in the specified Content Block.

They have completely different use cases.

I imagine that in the content block that you are referencing, you have some kind of a LookupRows and RowCount combination, which in the end returns a number, and inside the Exclusion Script Block you are checking if the number returned is greater than 0. The evaluation of the Exclusion Script will then either return true or false, and based on that it will send or exclude the email from sending.

However, if the content block you are referencing is not returning a number but a true/false value, you should remove the "greater than 0" part from the exclusion script, because that would simply not work (comparing true/false with numbers).

Now, regarding the TreatAsContent function, you shouldn't need it here - it would only make sense to use it, if your content block was expected to return a piece of AMPscript, such as `%%=v(@rowCount)=%%` for example. Then the TreatAsContent function would force the evaluation of the nested AMPscript within the returned string and result in outputting the value of the @rowCount variable.

Hope this makes sense and your exclusion script works as expected!